# Record triggered flow not working for email message and case object to update the owner ID

Tags: visual-workflow, case, salesforce-id, emailmessage

I have working to convert the workflow into flow for the below scenario.

But Am not sure, Why its not triggering, where I done the mistakes and why its hanging to trigger the flow. Please see the scenario below and help me to get the result.

Objects : Case and email message.

Scenario:

The scenario was, whenever the email "To address" is equals to **ABC@gmail.com** (sample) , "Status" is equals to **New** and incoming equals **True** in email message object and Brand in case object is equals to **MCDonald's**  means that case should moves to expected queue. I mean that case owner ID should update the expected queue name on that case.

So I setup the below condition in flow based on the requirements. But its does not works.

```
Condition : (Object : email message) 
Email  = ABC@gmail.com
Status = New
Incoming = True

Condition : (Object : Case)
Brand = MCDonald's 

Need to Update values : ( Object : Case) 

Owner ID : Sample queue.
```

I created the "Record Triggered flow" with entry conditions and related with ID for email message and Case. But am not aware still where I pending to add the required elements in the flow. Please anyone review and guide me to complete this flow.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you should add a fourth entry condition: `caseId isNull false` so you filter out non-E2C incoming emails.  Otherwise, this looks fine. What does Flow debug look like? Use [edit] - no comments please

Comment: @cropredy - As you said, I have added the Fourth entry condition too as caseId is Null false (please see the last Screenshot above). But still it does not works . And I cant debug the email message flows, because am not able to debug the email related flows. so am doing the real-time testing. But this flow not triggering and am not get the result yet now.

Comment: You can debug email flows.  Add debug log for the automated case user.

Comment: Are these emails creating new cases or getting attached to an existing case? If creating a new case, I know the caseid won't be populated on insert.

Comment: @Daniel Hoechst - These emails are not creating new cases, Its need to update the existing case records once the flow was triggered with Conditions MET.

Comment: Have you tried changing your entry criteria to run before update? I wonder if the initial insert doesn't have the case id populated.

Comment: No. I tried with made the changes in entry criteria's too .  But It does not work. I think , I missed to make the relation with the ID's on somewhere in the flow. But I don't know exactly where I missed.

My Requirement is simple , The Incoming -> true , Status -> New and To address -> ABC @gmail.com in email message  object and Brand = MC Donalds in Case object.
If this conditions are met  means --> the existing case record owner id need to change into specific queue name in case object.

But I don't know why its creating a challenges to trigger the flow.